# Find User for a JWT token in devise-jwt in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, jwt, actioncable

I am using devise-jwt for token based authentication in my RoR app. 
The client sends in a token in the header like so: `Bearer #{token}`
By using `authenticate_user!` I am able to authenticate the user in the controller, and get the logged in user as `current_user`.

When I use Actioncable, the connect method in connection.rb requires to find the user from the token. The connection.rb is as follows:

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      token = request.env["Authorization"]
      find_verified_user
    end

    private
    def find_verified_user
      if authenticate_user!
        self.current_user = current_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However, the `authenticate_user!` is not a valid method here (as it is devise specific).

My question is how to I find the current_user here? How to identify the client who has sent the token in the header?

Comment: maybe `Warden::JWTAuth::UserDecoder.new.call(token, :user, nil)` wil helpful. It will return user match to the token

Comment: Yups, seems to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to retrieve the user from the `JWT` token is to use the `Warden::JWTAuth` helper:

```rb
Warden::JWTAuth::UserDecoder.new.call(token, :user, nil)
=> #<User id: 1, email: "user@email.com", ...>
```

or use `JWT` directly:

```rb
decoded_token = JWT.decode(token, 'jwt_secret', true, { algorithm: 'jwt_algorithm' })
=>
   [
     {
       "sub" => "1",
       "scp" => "user",
       "aud" => nil,
       "iat" => 1689090581,
       "exp" => 1691682581,
       "jti" => "7f82dcc8-4957-4fa8-95dd-20a26989343c"
     },
     {
       "alg" => "HS256"
     }
   ]

User.find((decoded_token[0])['sub']))
=> #<User id: 1, email: "user@email.com", ...>
```

(where `jwt_algorithm` is usually `HS256`)